# How can I exclude nomenclature from the table of contents in amsart?

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature, amsart

I would like to exclude nomenclature from the table of contents in amsart.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}

\makenomenclature  

\makeindex

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\nomenclature[000]{$Hi$}{World}

\makenomenclature  

\printnomenclature[1in]

\section{world}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsart` tries hard to include every section, even unnumbered ones, in the table of contents. Why wouldn't you want the nomenclature?

Comment: For purely aestethic reasons. The table of contents is right in front of the List of Notations:(

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Sorry, we simultaneously edited:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsart` class tries hard to include *every* sectional unit in the table of contents, even the unnumbered ones.

It's possible to achieve what you want with some hack.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% copy the formatting of section titles
\let\nomencl@section\section
% if the level is greater than 1000, then amsart
% doesn't include the section's title in the toc
\patchcmd{\nomencl@section}{{1}}{{1001}}{}{}
% patch \thenomenclature to call \nomencl@section
% instead of \section*
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\section*}
  {\nomencl@section}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
\makenomenclature

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\nomenclature[000]{$Hi$}{World}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printnomenclature[1in]

\section{world}
\end{document}
```

The `arara` directives make compiling the document easy (but do no harm if you don't use arara).

[image]

Note that your second `\makenomenclature` instruction and `\makeindex` do nothing, so I removed them.

Answer (score 5):

from time to time it's necessary (or desirable) to change or omit a heading from the toc.
since the ams document classes by default include even starred chapters (and sections, etc.) in the toc, such changes must be made explicitly.

an entry in the ams author faq is "[How can I omit or change a heading in the table of contents?](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238)".  it tells how to create a command `\SkipTocEntry` (the definition depends on whether or not `hyperref` is involved; both versions are given) and use it to modify the toc.  here is the code for removing an entry.

in the preamble,

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[5]{}
```

(if `hyperref` is not involved, change `[5]` to `[4]`.)

just before the command that will write the entry into the `.toc` file, insert the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
```

in the present case, inserting this line just before `\printnomenclature[1in]` should do the job, but since latex sometimes delays certain commands until after they're actually needed, this needs to be checked by experiment.  (for example, if the `SkipTocEntry` is placed before an `\include` line, it won't be processed until after that `\include`d file is completed, which is too late; in that situation, the `\SkipTocEntry` must be placed in the `\include`d file.)

see the full author faq entry for additional details.