# How to have a section without number and not in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I have a document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

That's how I produce the title and ToC:

```
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
```

I have a section

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}
```

for which I do not want a listing in the ToC and no numbering. The star disables the numbering but still it appears in the ToC:

[image]

I googled at lot and read many threads in this forum but didn't find the solution. Other answers suggest that the star would already do the trick but as you can see in my screenshot it doesn't.

Comment: Did you find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex) to a similar question?

Comment: One possibility is, immediately before the instruction `\section*{Acknowledgment}` to issue the instruction `\addtocontents{toc}{\makeatletter \def\@toclevel{0} \makeatother}`, and after the section is set, restore the previous `\@toclevel` value.

Comment: @barbarabeeton So what is the command after `\section*{Acknowledgment}`?

Comment: Following `\section*` insert the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}}`.  But I should add that the answer by @Οὖτις was developed at AMS and should work unless `hyperref` is used.  If `hyperref` is used, a modification is necessary; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131719 from which that answer was "stolen".  (That answer may render this question a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

The idea was shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131719/237192).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to have some blindtext

\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{} % stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131719/237192
\newcommand{\hiddensection}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}\section*{#1}} % easier version

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Introduction} % not hidden from toc
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry} % hidden from toc using original command combination
    \section*{Acknowledgement}
    \lipsum[2][1-5]

    \hiddensection{Another hidden section} % hidden from toc using shorthand
    \lipsum[3][1-5]

    \section{Next visible section}
    \lipsum[4][1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]